# Primary key scanning in partitioned table

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, plpgsql

I have really big table, which I need to be partitioned by date (via trigger in my case).
The problem I've encountered is I can get data by timestamp filter pretty fast, but can't get good performance while extracting data for certain row by primary key.

The main table is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE parent_table (
    guid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), -- This is gonna be the primary key
    tm timestamptz NOT NULL, -- Timestamp, on which paritions are based
    value int4 not null default -1, -- Just a value
    CONSTRAINT z_detections_pk PRIMARY KEY (guid)
);
CREATE INDEX parent_table_tm_idx ON dev.dev_z_detections USING btree (tm DESC);
```

Then I create simple trigger for creation new parition if there are new date

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION parent_table_insert_fn()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    schema_name           varchar(255)        := 'public';
    table_master          varchar(255)        := 'parent_table';
    table_part            varchar(255)        := '';
    table_date_underscore varchar(255)        := '';
    constraint_tm_start timestamp with time zone;
    constraint_tm_end timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN
    table_part := table_master || '_' || to_char(timezone('utc', new.tm), 'YYYY_MM_DD');
    table_date_underscore := '' || to_char(timezone('utc', new.tm), 'YYYY_MM_DD');
    PERFORM
        1
    from
        information_schema.tables 
    WHERE 
      table_schema = schema_name
      AND table_name = table_part
    limit 1;
    IF NOT FOUND
    then
        constraint_tm_start := to_char(timezone('utc', new.tm), 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp at time zone 'utc';
        constraint_tm_end := constraint_tm_start + interval '1 day';
    execute '
      CREATE TABLE ' || schema_name || '.' || table_part || ' (
          CONSTRAINT parent_table_' || table_date_underscore || '_pk PRIMARY KEY (guid),
          CONSTRAINT parent_table_' || table_date_underscore || '_ck CHECK ( tm >= ' || QUOTE_LITERAL(constraint_tm_start) || ' and tm < ' || QUOTE_LITERAL(constraint_tm_end) || ' )
      ) INHERITS (' || schema_name || '.' || table_master || ');
      CREATE INDEX parent_table_' || table_date_underscore || '_tidx ON ' || schema_name || '.' || table_part || ' USING btree (tm desc);
    ';
    END IF;
    execute '
        INSERT INTO ' || schema_name || '.' || table_part || '
        SELECT ( (' || QUOTE_LITERAL(NEW) || ')::' || schema_name || '.' || TG_RELNAME || ' ).*;';   
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$function$
;
```

Enable trigger on parent table:

```
create trigger parent_table_insert_fn_trigger before insert
on parent_table for each row execute function parent_table_insert_fn();
```

And insert some data in it:

```
insert into parent_table(guid, tm, value)
values
('1f4835c0-2b22-4cfc-ab3c-940af679ace6', '2021-04-06 14:00:00+03:00', 1),
('5ca37d57-e79e-4e1f-ace7-91eb671f3a82', '2021-04-07 15:30:00+03:00', 2),
('b57bfbf6-7ed0-4dde-a40b-9fa2e6f24808', '2021-04-07 17:10:00+03:00', 3),
('ad69cd35-5b20-466f-9d5c-61fa5d41bc5f', '2021-04-08 16:50:00+03:00', 66),
('bb0ec87a-72bb-438e-8f4c-2cdc3ae7d525', '2021-03-21 19:00:00+03:00', -10);
```

After those manipulations I've got 4 tables:

```
parent_table
parent_table_2021_03_21
parent_table_2021_04_06
parent_table_2021_04_07
parent_table_2021_04_08
```

Checking if indexing works good for timestamps filter:

```
explain analyze
select * from parent_table where tm > '2021-04-07 10:00:00+03:00' and tm <= '2021-04-07 16:30:00+03:00';

> > >
Append  (cost=0.00..14.43 rows=8 width=28) (actual time=0.017..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on parent_table parent_table_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: ((tm > '2021-04-07 10:00:00+03'::timestamp with time zone) AND (tm <= '2021-04-07 16:30:00+03'::timestamp with time zone))
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on parent_table_2021_04_07 parent_table_2  (cost=4.22..14.39 rows=7 width=28) (actual time=0.013..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((tm > '2021-04-07 10:00:00+03'::timestamp with time zone) AND (tm <= '2021-04-07 16:30:00+03'::timestamp with time zone))
        Heap Blocks: exact=1
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on parent_table_2021_04_07_tidx  (cost=0.00..4.22 rows=7 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((tm > '2021-04-07 10:00:00+03'::timestamp with time zone) AND (tm <= '2021-04-07 16:30:00+03'::timestamp with time zone))
Planning Time: 0.381 ms
Execution Time: 0.053 ms
```

This is fine and works as I expected.

But selecting by certain primary key gives me next analyze's output:

```
explain analyze
select * from parent_table where guid = 'b57bfbf6-7ed0-4dde-a40b-9fa2e6f24808';

> > >
Append  (cost=0.00..32.70 rows=5 width=28) (actual time=0.021..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on parent_table parent_table_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (guid = 'b57bfbf6-7ed0-4dde-a40b-9fa2e6f24808'::uuid)
  ->  Index Scan using parent_table_2021_04_06_pk on parent_table_2021_04_06 parent_table_2  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (guid = 'b57bfbf6-7ed0-4dde-a40b-9fa2e6f24808'::uuid)
  ->  Index Scan using parent_table_2021_04_07_pk on parent_table_2021_04_07 parent_table_3  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (guid = 'b57bfbf6-7ed0-4dde-a40b-9fa2e6f24808'::uuid)
  ->  Index Scan using parent_table_2021_04_08_pk on parent_table_2021_04_08 parent_table_4  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (guid = 'b57bfbf6-7ed0-4dde-a40b-9fa2e6f24808'::uuid)
  ->  Index Scan using parent_table_2021_03_21_pk on parent_table_2021_03_21 parent_table_5  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (guid = 'b57bfbf6-7ed0-4dde-a40b-9fa2e6f24808'::uuid)
Planning Time: 0.345 ms
Execution Time: 0.076 ms
```

And this query gives me bad perfomance (I guess?) especially on really big paritioned tables like 10M+ rows for each partition.

**So my question is**: what should I do to evade partitions scans for simple primary key lookup?

Note: I'm using PostgreSQL 13.1

**UPDATE 2021-04-07 15:22+03:00**:
So, in semi-production table I have such results:

1. Timestamp filter

```
Append  (cost=0.00..809.35 rows=16616 width=32) (actual time=0.037..5.612 rows=16865 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on wifi_logs t_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: ((tm >= '2020-04-07 14:00:00+03'::timestamp with time zone) AND (tm <= '2020-04-07 17:00:00+03'::timestamp with time zone))
  ->  Index Scan using wifi_logs_tm_idx_2020_04_07 on wifi_logs_2020_04_07 t_2  (cost=0.29..726.27 rows=16615 width=32) (actual time=0.026..4.655 rows=16865 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((tm >= '2020-04-07 14:00:00+03'::timestamp with time zone) AND (tm <= '2020-04-07 17:00:00+03'::timestamp with time zone))
Planning Time: 14.869 ms
Execution Time: 6.151 ms
```

2. GUID (primary key filter)

```
  ->  Seq Scan on wifi_logs t_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (guid = '78bc5537-4f2f-4e83-8abd-4241ac3f9f27'::uuid)
  ->  Seq Scan on wifi_logs_2014_12_04 t_4  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (guid = '78bc5537-4f2f-4e83-8abd-4241ac3f9f27'::uuid)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
  --
  -- TONS OF PARTITION TABLE SCANS
  ---
  ->  Index Scan using wifi_logs_2021_03_18_pk on wifi_logs_2021_03_18 t_387  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (guid = '78bc5537-4f2f-4e83-8abd-4241ac3f9f27'::uuid)
  ->  Seq Scan on wifi_logs_1970_01_01 t_388  (cost=0.00..3.60 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (guid = '78bc5537-4f2f-4e83-8abd-4241ac3f9f27'::uuid)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 119
  ->  Index Scan using wifi_logs_2021_03_19_pk on wifi_logs_2021_03_19 t_389  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (guid = '78bc5537-4f2f-4e83-8abd-4241ac3f9f27'::uuid)
  --
  -- ANOTHER TONS OF PARTITION TABLE SCANS
  ---
  ->  Index Scan using wifi_logs_2021_04_07_pk on wifi_logs_2021_04_07 t_408  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (guid = '78bc5537-4f2f-4e83-8abd-4241ac3f9f27'::uuid)
Planning Time: 97.662 ms
Execution Time: 36.756 ms
```

Comment: You should be using native partitioning in Postgres which is a lot faster than inheritance based partitioning. But in any case: if you query doesn't include the partitioning key, then this will always be slower than doing the same on a non-partitioned table.

Comment: Execution Time: 0.076 ms, what kind of performance are you looking for?

Comment: @FrankHeikens If I have 1500+ partitions it gets pretty slow actual querying (not as fast as I query single huge table without those partitions)

*upd*: and 0.076 still slower than 0.053 for more compilcated condition (timestamps filtering)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
I'll update question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Updated question: just gave example output from semi-production database

Comment: Well, if you have that many partitions and you have a query without a WHERE condition on the partition key, there is no other way to scan all partitions. That is always going to be slower than scanning a single table that is not partitioned. Maybe you simply don't have a good case for partitioning here.

Comment: The query plan proves that the index is not the real problem, it's the planning time: 97.662 ms. Execution is almost 3 times faster. Using less partitions (a lot les) will improve performance.

Comment: Don't I loose perfomance in case when I reduce partitions number? For e.g.: replacement of date-partitions with week-partitions will strongly affect timestamp filter, won't it? (but I will get benefits on primary key lookup)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, and there is no way to avoid it except

1. create fewer partitions, so that you have to scan fewer partitions
2. add a condition on `tm` to the query to avoid scanning them all

You will notice that the planning time greatly exceeds the query execution time. To help with that, you can

1. create fewer partitions, so that the optimizer has less work to do
2. use prepared statements to avoid the planing effort